# PHP setTimeZone timezone conversion issues - peculiarities due to BST (GMT+1)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a datetime field stored in my mysql database which contains a time for an event set in UK time. In the example used below this time is 09:00.

I am attempting to display this time also in West Coast and East Coast USA timezones.

I believe I'm using the php DateTime 'setTimeZone' function correctly - however the results coming back are an hour out for both timezones

```
$online->getTimeByZone('America/Los_Angeles'); // Returns 02:00
$online->getTimeByZone('America/New_York'); // Returns 05:00


public function getTimeByZone($timezone = 'Europe/London') {

   $date = $this->getDateField('start_time', 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2017-10-30 09:00:00 

   $datetime = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
   $datetime->setTimeZone(new dateTimeZone($timezone));

   return $datetime->format('H:i');

}
```

I am assuming from the hour difference this is going to be related to the UK observing Daylight Savings Time - but I would have expected as I'm initiating the DateTime object with 'Europe/London' this to be factored in.

Any ideas?

Comment: in which timezone you want an time ?

Comment: @Hackit the database is storing the value in 'Europe/London' time. I'm looking to convert to and output in US East Coast ('America/New_York') and US West Coast ('America/Los_Angeles') times.

This is working - but the times output by my function are incorrect at 2am and 5am when they should be 1am and 4am.

Comment: Actually, in October 30th 2017, London is not in DST [(it ends in October 29th)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london?year=2017), while both [New York](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york?year=2017) and [Los Angeles](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/los-angeles?year=2017) are in DST (both ends in November). So, in Oct 30th, 9 AM in London is equals to 2 AM in Los Angeles and 5 AM in New York (due to all those DST rules): https://www.worldtimebuddy.com/?qm=1&lid=2643743,5128581,5368361&h=2643743&date=2017-10-30&sln=9-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have picked an example date that occurs in the small window when North America is still observing "Daylight Saving Time", but the UK is not observing "Summer Time": UK clocks change on the last Sunday in October, but USA and Canadian clocks on the first Sunday in November.

During this overlap week, America/New_York time is UTC-4 ("Eastern Daylight Time"), and Europe/London time is UTC+0 ("Greenwich Mean Time"). Consequently, "2017-10-30 09:00:00 Europe/London" is indeed "2017-10-30 05:00:00 America/New_York".

If you pick a date a week earlier, the offsets will be UTC-4 and UTC+1 ("British Summer Time"); a week later, they will be UTC-5 ("Eastern Standard Time") and UTC+0; so for most of the year, you would be correct that the expected difference would be 5 hours.

There is another two weeks in March where North America changes its clocks earlier, so again there will be a 4-hour offset instead of 5.

(The same of course applies to the America/Los_Angeles timezone, which will be 6 instead of 7 hours away during these three weeks.)